# EditContext is null — Page Properties dialog will not open

Tags: aem

Using the standard `init.jsp` from `/libs/foundation/components/page/`, there is a line in the head of my page to provide the dialog path:

```
if (editContext != null && editContext.getComponent() != null) {
    dlgPath = editContext.getComponent().getDialogPath();
}
```

editContext here is returning `null`, which means the dialog won't load for the page itself. Components on the page are unaffected & from the context menu on the site admin, the page dialog will also load without issue.

Above is using the standard `cq:defineObjects` tag to initialise `editContext`, though it will also return null via `WCMUtils.getComponentContext(request).getEditContext()`

The ComponentContext returns fine. If I adapt `init.jsp` to use `componentContext.getComponent().getDialogPath()`, the dialog will load successfully, but I want to avoid tampering with `init.jsp`.

I know this is an issue with my own bespoke code (Geometrixx is unaffected), but I'm not sure how to debug why the EditContext is failing to load.

Comment: Are you sure componentContext.getComponent().getDialogPath() is returning the dialog path while your editContext is null? Could you provide additional details regarding the structure of your page component?

Comment: Yes — have them both evaluated out in the JSP to cross-check. I'm hitting a servlet as the main entry point to the template & then forwarding on to the JSP. This is really the only non-standard element, so I know it's likely related to this, but can't see how it's interfering with the EditContext.